# What are solutions to train remote teams?

Tags: programming, streaming, sharing

I am to train several teams on software development. I am use to it and I always get the people I train to start working on katas very early during my course to challenge them and check if they understood each chapter.

The catch is that some of the people I have to train are off shore. They are first far away and second on a completely different time zone.

I am looking for a solution that will help me :

1. Assign people with coding exercises which they can then submit
   whenever they want
2. Check their code's evolution (i.e. I'd like to
   not have a simple github repository, i want to see how they dealt
   with the specific problem I gave them)
3. Ideally have the
   possibility to make anotation to their solution and challenge them

I've tried the Live Share solution on vscode as a MVP but it's locked on that company's network.
I'd like to try [qualified.io](https://www.qualified.io/) but I've been trying to get a trial period for 2 days and no one has answered me yet.

What kind of alternatives can you suggest ? 
Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to train in specific Technology / Language or any popular language? You tagged it [streaming] - do you want to watch them working in real-time?

Comment: Any popular language. Mainly c# and Java. I added streaming as a nice to have but it's not mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest:

1. [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/) - you can host your Jupyter server and add every one of your programmers some task. They'll be able to write their solutions in 'cells', so you would be able to watch their "code's evolution". Each cel can be run on it's own, so it would be easier for them to test it mid-task. It works best for interpreter languages (Python, R), but there are kernels (support) for Java and many more languages. 
   You could open single notebook for each task and track their reasoning.
2. [GitHub](https://github.com/) - I'd suggest you to rethink this. Java and C# are usually used for bigger projests (at least few classes). Of course you can test algorithms in Java, but corporate work quite often requires API's, GUI's and stuff that you can't store in single file. Maybe give your developers task and make them learn git. You can see their code, comment it and see their changes (PRs). They will learn important things like git, git-flow, ssk-keys and more.
3. [CodeWars](https://www.codewars.com/) or [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/) - smaller tasks. CodeWars have online compiler and can be easier. It also has some interesting tasks, to train your language skills. Project Euler is great for more advanced, algorithm based tasks. Require some knowledge of math and separate IDE.